Big query data discrepancy
I created two views

365 days
1 Year

If I run same query on both views, I see difference in results for same month.
For example, If I see June of 2023 from the 365 days view and the 1 year view. They are different number of rows. I expected it to be same as it is for the exact same query, only the underlying tables differs in time denomination. One table uses day and other uses year.
Can someone help me understand the discrepancy here?
I tried verifying that if I create view with same time denomination, e.g, year, the data for a particular interval matches exactly.
For example, If I create views for 1 year and 2 year and then take the data for June of 2023, the number of rows match exactly.

Hard to tell without any SQL and info about the diff, but please remember that 2024 is a leap year.

Please provide the actual SQL for the base table(s) and the views. Also, the queries you ran that returned different results.

The issue is to do with the difference between 365 days and YEAR.
Get today's date:
SELECT CURRENT_DATE

returns 2024-08-08
Get today's date minus 365 days:
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 365 DAY)

returns 2023-08-09
Get today's date minus 1 year:
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

Returns 2023-08-08, i.e. today's date, but substitute the year (2024) for year-1, i.e. 2023.
Your views are returning 1 day's different results at the oldest edge of the dataset.
